# scala - convert mahout vector to array

Tags: java, arrays, scala, vector, mahout

I'm using mahout math vector (`org.apache.mahout.math.Vector`)
and want to convert it into an array.

Looking on the [documentation](http://search-lucene.com/jd/mahout/math/org/apache/mahout/math/Vector.html) I didn't find a function to convert with.

What is the simplest way to convert it (using scala)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JavaConverters (I don't have mahout, so there could be a minor error in the code):

```
val javaIterable = mahoutVector.all()
import scala.collection.JavaConverters.iterableAsScalaIterableConverter
val scalaIterable = javaIterable.asScala
val scalaArray = scalaIterable.toArray
```

scalaArray now contains Vector.Element objects. If you want to have the double values, you have to map the elements (with .get()):

```
[same first three lines as above]
val scalaArray = scalaIterable.map(_.get()).toArray
```

Comment: @webSpider why do you use var and not val? :-)

Comment: something called inmutability, you know :)

Comment: In Scala (and other functional programming languages) immutability is favored over mutability. This has some advantages, e.g. you can reason better about what happens in your program and it simplifies concurrent programming.

Comment: It depends. Sometimes it is necessary to use mutability, but one should minimize it. There are numerous articles about that topic in the web, I recommend to read a few of them.

Answer (score 1):

The latest master version of Mahout has a pretty full featured Scala API and linear Algebra DSL. New Code is being written in Scala and targeted for Spark. In fact no new contributions are accepted for Hadoop mapreduce, only Spark.

Scala and Spark bindings are described here: http://mahout.apache.org/users/sparkbindings/ScalaSparkBindings.pdf

There is even a Scala Shell where you can interactively experiment with a lot of the core Mahout code.

You may not need an array given the new ways to manipulate Vectors and Matricies in Scala.